# When I stop pedaling my bike the rear gears keep turning, is this an easy fix? Bike is a vintage Raleigh Grand Prix

Tags: hub

Raleigh Grand Prix chain and rear hub keep turning when coasting

Comment: If you do this, do you hear a clicking noise as the wheel turns?

Comment: Assuming you have a freewheel, you can try lubricating it. Worst case is having to replace that freewheel. This may seem like a dumb question, but can you confirm that you have a freewheel in the rear? Alternatives would be a fixed gear or the short-lived Shimano "front freewheel" where the pedals remain motionless while the chain and chainrings keep turning during coasting.

Comment: Stupid question:  Do you have a freewheeling crank?  Some bikes are designed to work this way, as it makes shifting easier, especially for the novice.

Comment: Clarify please : Do you have a rear derailleur and a multi-cog cassette at the back?   Could be a fixed gear conversion.

Comment: Clarify - if you're riding along and you stop pedalling, can you push down on the rearmost pedal to have it coast normally, or does the pedal push your foot around in a circle no matter how hard you resist it?

Comment: Futher info - this model name was used in 1974 and 2011, maybe not continuously but there's a large time window for this bike.  It could look like this 1974  https://thecabe.com/forum/attachments/raleighgs1-jpg.146502/  or this 2011 model   https://www.rei.com/media/f46ab4eb-dd51-4b41-a4d9-18bf776f13f6

Answer (score 1):

When you stop pedaling the freewheel on the back wheel is supposed to spin so that the wheels can keep turning but the chain, and the pedals are stationary.

Something is preventing the freewheel from doing it's job.
First guess is that it needs lubrication.

Repair Options:

- Pull the rear wheel off and try working a little oil into the freewheel. This involves turning the freewheel backwards while applying oil in the gap between the moving part of the freewheel and the stationary part.
- Disassemble the freewheel and lubricate
- Replace the freewheel. This will require a special tool, your local bike shop should be able to help you. If it's off the bike some will remove the freewheel for free - others will charge.

Part number 42 in this diagram from [Sheldon Brown's website](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/retroraleighs/catalogs/1977-drawings/pages/30-sprite-dl90.html)

[image]

Here is an list of the previous answers to this question (not a complete list). These articles contain information on what lubrication to use and detailed instructions for lubricating a freewheel.
["How should I lubricate my Shimano freewheel?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/13900/how-should-i-lubricate-my-shimano-freewheel)
["What should I use to lubricate a freehub?"](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/5732/what-should-i-use-to-lubricate-a-freehub)
[Bike pedals turning when coasting (not a fixed gear)](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/34225/bike-pedals-turning-when-coasting-not-a-fixed-gear/34226#34226)

By the way, Sheldon has an article on the [Raleigh Grand Prix](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/retroraleighs/grand-prix.html) 1968 to 1977 and a [Raleigh catalogue archive](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/retroraleighs/index.html#catalogues)